# Create new array from hiera_hash, but avoid nested data

Tags: puppet, hiera

I have a hiera_hash that looks like this:

```
signalfx_custom_receivers:
  smartagent/http1:
    type: http
    host: "es.mydomain.tv"
    useHTTPS: true
  smartagent/http2:
    type: http
    host: "es.other.tv"
    useHTTPS: true
  smartagent/http3:
    type: http
    host: "pmd-akamai.cdn.mydomain.tv"
    useHTTPS: true
```

I'm trying to generate an array from this to use elsewhere. The array should only contain smartagent values, so should looks like this:

```
[smartagent/http1, smartagent/http2, smartagent/http3]
```

I've tried the following:

```
$signalfx_custom_pipeline   = Array($signalfx_custom_receivers)
```

However, this includes all of the nested key/values, and ends up looking like this:

```
[["smartagent/http1", {"type"=>"http", "host"=>"es.mydomain.tv", "useHTTPS"=>true}], ["smartagent/http2", {"type"=>"http", "host"=>"es.other.tv", "useHTTPS"=>true}], ["smartagent/http3", {"type"=>"http", "host"=>"pmd-akamai.cdn.mydomain.tv", "useHTTPS"=>true}]]
```

How can I generate an array, but avoid adding these nested values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm trying to generate an array from this to use elsewhere. The array should only contain smartagent values

That is, the *keys* of the hash.  Extracting these is exactly what the built-in [`keys()`](https://www.puppet.com/docs/puppet/7/function.html#keys) function does:

```bash
$signalfx_custom_pipeline = keys($signalfx_custom_receivers)

# or

$signalfx_custom_pipeline = $signalfx_custom_receivers.keys()
```

The two forms behave identically, but personally, I find the second clearer in this case.